# What's the difference between "call off" vs. "cancel"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, phrasal-verbs

> You have to get Chang *to call off* some of this homework.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist, as particularly appropriate on this site: ♫ *[You say either, I say either](http://www.lyrics007.com/Louis%20Armstrong%20Lyrics/Let%27s%20Call%20The%20Whole%20Thing%20Off%20Lyrics.html)* ♫

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Their meanings overlap a great deal, but there are some differences in where you use it.

To *call off* something naturally comes from cancelling something by shouting out an order, but has spread to mean almost any form of cancelling.

In some expressions it could be confusing to use *call off* instead of *cancel*, for example when cancelling a subscription.

Similarly some uses of *call off* can't just be replaced by *cancel*, for example in the expression *call off the dogs*. To use *cancel* instead, you would have to specify that it's the action of the dogs that should be cancelled, not the dogs themselves.

Comment: I think I need to disagree. When planning a party expecting a clown, then deciding you don't want him, people say ``cancel the clown``. Therefore, I believe ``cancel the dogs`` could be used the same way.

Comment: @RiMMER: Then it would have a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

They have some special usages:

- To "call off" : to decide that a
  planned event, **especially a sports
  event**, will not happen:

> Tomorrow's match has been called off
>   because of the icy weather.

- To "cancel" : *to stop an order for
  goods or services that you no longer
  want*:

> to cancel a magazine subscription